# Can etheric rounds be made for any weapon?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e, weapons, hunter-the-vigil

Etheric rounds state they come specifically for set weapons (flamethrowers are weapons, so we're good so far).

But they also specifically state that they are bullets. Which is a shame as flamethrowers don't shoot bullets!

Do etheric rounds need to be bullets, or can they be used in any weapon?

Comment: This might be better as an elaboration on the question you've already asked about proton packs.

Comment: @Jadasc I see them as separate. But I get where you're coming from.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strictly RAW, I'd say no:

> Etheric Rounds (1 to 5; Renewable)
>   Produced in top-secret, experimental laboratories around the country, **these bullets have been bombarded with a cocktail of exotic, high-energy particles that infuse peculiar pseudo-physical properties into the lead**.

Emphasis mine ^^

However, I've found that most of the World of Darkness games provide rules that can be dressed up as you like.

Ask with your Storyteller if the same procedure could be applied to the inflammable fluid of a flamethrower.

I'd say It should't affect the balance of the game (since the supernaturals entities are a LOT more powerful anyway) :D